# rpi gpio node are not present on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos

I installed Node Red (v 0.16.2) on OSX (10.11) using NPM and Node JS of course. All is working nice, excepted, some node are missing on the left palette. I saw with some video tutos. It seems rpi gpio node are set up by default. But there is no rpi gpio node in my palette and no more when I try to add them using "manage palette"

Does someone knows how to set up these nodes ?

Answer (score -1):

There is no GPIO node because Mac doesn't have GPIO. But you can plug in a little usb shield to the Mac to give him access to GPIO. May be there is something to do to help Node Red to "see" the usb shield...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19045772)

Comment: It's a part of the answer. It seems Node Red doesn't display GPIO because of the Mac hardware. I'm not sure but it's a start of solution.

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum, answers are expected to answer the question. If this doesn't answer the question (which I think is what your saying) then it shouldn't be an answer. If this add's details edit the question.

Comment: I think I answered, no ? There is no possibility to add GPIO node on iMac because of the hardware. This is an answer. I've find out this answer by myself elsewhere and i felt usefull to write it there to help others users.